# Binding and x:Bind problems with TwoWay mode

Tags: c#, windows, data-binding, win-universal-app, windows-10

I've encountered weird issue, which I cannot understand. In main page I've only one button which navigates to second page and holds my model:

```cs
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaiseProperty(string property) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

    private int index = 0;
    public int Index
    {
        get { Debug.WriteLine($"Getting value {index}"); return index; }
        set { Debug.WriteLine($"Setting value {value}"); index = value; RaiseProperty(nameof(Index)); }
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public static Model MyModel = new Model();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().AppViewBackButtonVisibility = AppViewBackButtonVisibility.Visible;
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += (s, e) => { if (Frame.CanGoBack) { e.Handled = true; Frame.GoBack(); } };
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage));
}
```

On second page there is only *ComboBox* which has two way binding in *SelectedIndex*:

```xml
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="{x:Bind MyModel.Index, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <x:String>First</x:String>
        <x:String>Second</x:String>
        <x:String>Third</x:String>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
{
    public Model MyModel => MainPage.MyModel;

    public BlankPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Unloaded += (s, e) => Debug.WriteLine("--- page unloaded ---");
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Nothing extraordinary. The problem is that I get two different outputs when I use `Binding` and `x:Bind`, but the worst is that after every new navigation to same page the property's getter (and setter in `x:Bind`) is called more and more times:

[image]

The *old* page still resides in memory and is still subscribed to property, that is understandable. If we run `GC.Collect()` after returning from page, we will begin from start.

But if we use old *Binding* with *one-way* and selection changed event:

```xml
<ComboBox SelectedIndex="{Binding MyModel.Index, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionChanged="ComboBox_SelectionChanged">
```

along with the eventhandler:

```cs
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0 && e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault() != null)
        MyModel.Index = (sender as ComboBox).Items.IndexOf(e.AddedItems.FirstOrDefault());
}
```

then it will work 'properly' - only one getter and setter, no matter how many times we navigate to page before.

So my main questions are:

- where this difference in *one-way* - *two-way* binding comes from?
- taking into account that *one-way Binding* fires getter only once - is the described behavior of *two-way* desired/intended?
- how you deal with this *two-way* binding in case of multiple getters/setters getting called?

A working sample you can [download from here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=87995A9E6AADB641!63780&authkey=!AP_OTqub5PPlO6A&ithint=file%2czip).

Comment: Is this because of your static model instance? just my guess.

Comment: @KiranPaul No, with non-static it behaves exactly the same. I'm almost sure it's connected somehow with memory - if I fire `GC.Collect()` after returning to main page, then I'm back to beginning. Nevertheless I don't know why those two bindings differ so much and why for one-way the getter is always called once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually when you use `OneWay` binding with the `SectionChanged` event, only the *setter* of the `Index` property is called after changing the selection. The *getter* is never reached hence you don't see multiple *"Getting value ..."*.

But why is the *getter* not called??

Put a breakpoint on this line -

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
```

You will see that the value of `PropertyChanged` is `null`. So the `Invoke` method is never fired. I suspect this might be a bug in `ComboBox` with traditional binding set to `OneWay`. Whenever you change the selection, the binding is broken hence the `PropertyChanged` is `null`. If you change to use `x:Bind`, this problem goes away.

As you are already aware, the `GC` will only collect abandoned page instances when needed. So there are times when you see `Index` is referenced in multiple places, no matter which binding mechanism you chose.

One way to guarantee the *getter* and *setter* only get called once is to change the the `NavigationCacheMode` of your second `Page` to `Enabled/Required`. Doing so will ensure a single instance of the page.

Comment: I totally forgot about the *NavigationCacheMode*. Also nice catch with this propertychanged beng null. Thanks for help.

Comment: You're welcome. You always have interesting questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

Even after you navigated from and to a new `BlankPage` the other pages are still in the memory and still binded in your static model as @KiranPaul commented.

Now if you, as you commented, change in to no-static and still behaves the same, is because you make the same mistake. Even if it isn't static you still use the same variable from MainPage.(I think its not possible though, cause its not static)

So all the pages that are in the memory that havent `GC.Collect()`-ed will get the `PropertyChanged` event raised. Because the MyModel is always the same one.

Try this should work. Each time that you navigate to the BlankPage you instantiate a new Model and pass your index. Then when you unload the page you update the value in the MainPage.Model. That way when you leave the BlankPage you will only see a Set and a Get in Output.

```
 public sealed partial class BlankPage : Page
    {
        public Model MyModel = new Model() { Index = MainPage.MyModel.Index };

        public BlankPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Unloaded += (s, e) => { MainPage.MyModel.Index = MyModel.Index; Debug.WriteLine("--- page unloaded ---"); };
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Or when you leave BlankPage you can either:

- call `GC.Collect()`
- unbind the MyModel when you unload the page?

**Edit:**

With `Binding` it also does the same if you do it really fast. My guess is that the `GC.Collect()` is called

So I searched a bit and I found this:

[Binding vs. x:Bind, using StaticResource as a default and their differences in DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32582303/binding-vs-xbind-using-staticresource-as-a-default-and-their-differences-in-d)

An answer says:

> The {x:Bind} markup extension—new for Windows 10—is an alternative to {Binding}. {x:Bind} lacks some of the features of {Binding}, but it runs in less time and less memory than {Binding} and supports better debugging.

So Binding surely works different, it might calls `GC.Collect()` or Unbind it self??. Maybe have a look in [x:Bind markup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)

[image]

Comment: Couple of questions then: 1) what if I want to use one model defined in my app and not recreate it? 2) why `Binding` and `x:Bind` behave different? 3) why one-way binding works properly then? - always one getter, no matter how many times I navigate to a page (with static and non-static?

Comment: @Romasz check my edit. If unbind or call `GC.Collect()` I think you are OK.

Comment: Binding surely doesn't call `GC.Collect()`, you can even check it while debugging. Also I'm not sure what you mean by *it may Unbind itself*.

Comment: It was a joke that's what ?? was for :P.(English not mother language) Nvm that. Concluding, Binding and x:Bind have the same problem with one difference, in Binding it goes away fast! like `GC.Collect()` is called(Maybe it happens Native from the OS). Instead of x:Bind that if you dont do anything the problem persists. Now saying that it hit me

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add [tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to this binding to shed some light.

Also I would advise to swap these lines so that they look like this:

```
DataContext = this;
this.InitializeComponent();
```

It could be messing with your binding. As when you call initializeComponent it builds xaml tree but for binding I guess it uses old DataContext and then you immediately change DataContext, forcing rebinding of every property.